# Step Execution Status is not coming as Finished in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

In SpringBatch Job is not getting completed with the steps defined ,instead of that keep on going from Writer to Reader ,
while Debugging found context count is getting increased as 1
because of that Execution Status is coming as "CONTINUABLE" not "FINISHED".

Step1 is getting complete but step2 is having this issue..
please help..

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class PickUpBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private StepExecution stepExecution;


    @Bean
    public Job pickupJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("pickupJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(new JobResultListener())
            .start(readAndFilterBlockInventoryExtract())
            .next(blockKeyFetch())
            .next(processRequest())
           // .next(sendMessage())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public StepResultListener customStepListener() {
        return new StepResultListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step readAndFilterBlockInventoryExtract() {
        System.out.println("*****PickUpBatchConfig.readAndFilterBlockInventoryExtract********");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<BlockInventoryExtractProcessRequest<ProcessRequest>, BlockInventoryExtractProcessor.BlockInventoryExtractBuilder>chunk(0)
            .reader(new BlockInventoryReader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(new BlockInventoryWriter())
            .listener(promotionListener())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListener() {
        ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
        listener.setKeys(new String[] {"builder"});
        listener.setStrict(true);
        return listener;
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<BlockInventoryExtractProcessRequest<ProcessRequest>, BlockInventoryExtractProcessor.BlockInventoryExtractBuilder> processor() {
        return new BatchBlockInventoryExtractProcessor();
    }



    @Bean
    public Step blockKeyFetch() {
        System.out.println("PickUpBatchConfig.blockKeyFetch");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .<BlockInventoryExtractProcessor.BlockInventoryExtractBuilder,BlockInventoryExtractProcessor.BlockInventoryExtractBuilder>chunk(1)
            .reader(new BlockKeyReader())// Need to implement
            .processor(step2processor())
            .writer(new BlockKeyWriter())
            .listener(promotionListenerStep2())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListenerStep2() {
        ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
        listener.setKeys(new String[] {"blockKey"});
        listener.setStrict(true);
        return listener;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<BlockInventoryExtractProcessor.BlockInventoryExtractBuilder,BlockInventoryExtractProcessor.BlockInventoryExtractBuilder> step2processor() {
        return new BlockKeyProcess();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step processRequest() {
        System.out.println("PickUpBatchConfig.processRequest");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
            .<BlockInventoryExtractProcessor.BlockInventoryExtractBuilder, List<BlockInventoryExtractProcessRequest>>chunk(0)
            .reader(new ProcessRequestReader())//need to implement
            .processor(new ProcessRequestProcessor())
            .writer(new ProcessRequestWriter())
            .listener(promotionListenerStep3())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListenerStep3() {
        ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
        listener.setKeys(new String[] {"processRequest"});
        listener.setStrict(true);
        return listener;
    }
```

Comment: `CONTINUABLE` is usually an exit status of a tasklet, but your step 2 (`blockKeyFetch`) is chunk oriented. So unless one of its listeners is setting its status to `CONTINUABLE`, I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: @Mahamoud Ben Hassine : Do you think i need to do any change in my configuration?

Comment: I don't know, you need to check what sets the exit status to `CONTINUABLE` in your step 2.

Comment: ContextCount is coming as 1, because of that exit status says CONTINUABLE

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help you.